# JUnit Eclipse plugin source-code?

Tags: eclipse, open-source, junit, eclipse-plugin, flexunit

I'm looking into writing an Eclipse plugin for FlexUnit and was wondering where I could get the sources for the JUnit Eclipse plugin. I checked the JUnit sources at sourceforge but couldn't spot any code that looked like the plugin code.

Any idea where this code is available?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084176/how-do-i-configure-junits-source-in-eclipse

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find it on Eclipse's repository:

http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.pde.junit/

Comment: the CVS repo seems deprecated

Answer (score 11):

There are now git mirrors of the CVS repositories:

1. org.eclipse.jdt.junit: git://dev.eclipse.org/org.eclipse.jdt/org.eclipse.jdt.junit.git
2. org.eclipse.jdt.junit.core: git://dev.eclipse.org/org.eclipse.jdt/org.eclipse.jdt.junit.core.git
3. org.eclipse.jdt.junit.runtime: git://dev.eclipse.org/org.eclipse.jdt/org.eclipse.jdt.junit.runtime.git
4. org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime: git://dev.eclipse.org/org.eclipse.jdt/org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime.git

Comment: It's also mirrored on Github. For example, org.eclipse.jdt.junit can be found at:
https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ui

Comment: @porcoesphino the junit ones don't seem to be there.

Comment: Define "ones". You can find org.eclipse.jdt.junit at the link above or (slightly) more directly with this link: https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ui/tree/master/org.eclipse.jdt.junit

Comment: @porcoesphino sorry, you're right, didn't see them.

Answer (score 10):

Since you are in all likelihood using Eclipse, there's a far easier way to import it right into your workspace. The source is bundled with your eclipse distribution.

Just do
File -> Import -> Plug-ins and Fragments

Keep defaults ("Active target platform", "Select from all plug-ins" & "Projects with source folders"

Hit next, and select the JUnit plugin-packages and hit Finish, and they will be imported as Eclipse projects into your workspace.

Comment: This is awesome!!  However, it does not give source of Junit 4.8.2xxx