# How do I configure JUnit's Source in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I am using [Eclipse Galileo for Java EE](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/compare-packages), and I want to configure JUnit to show me the source code when I try to navigate to its methods. I've tried attaching source to the JUnit library, but the library definition is not editable. I cannot even find where to configure the JUnit library in the preferences.

When I open the Add Library window and choose JUnit, I see a dialog where I can choose the JUnit version, but it shows that Source Location is "not found".

How can I configure Eclipse to find JUnit's source?

Comment: Can someone please help me on this related question for eclipse STS ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51545313/how-do-i-make-eclipse-debugger-use-sources-jar-of-a-jar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I downloaded the Eclipse SDK and checked the differences, and I finally got it to work.

1. Download [this JAR](ftp://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/eclipse/eclipse/updates/3.5/R-3.5-200906111540/plugins/org.junit4.source_4.5.0.v20090423.jar) into your `eclipse/plugins` directory.
2. Edit the file `source.info` in your `eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.source` directory, and add the following line:

   > org.junit4.source,4.5.0.v20090423,plugins/org.junit4.source_4.5.0.v20090423.jar,-1,false
3. Open the file `artifacts.xml` in your `eclipse` directory, and add the following fragment:

   ```
   <artifact classifier='osgi.bundle' id='org.junit4.source' version='4.5.0.v20090423'>
     <properties size='2'>
       <property name='artifact.size' value='128389'/>
       <property name='download.size' value='128389'/>
     </properties>
   </artifact>
   ```
4. If Eclipse is already open, you'll need to restart it for the changes to be detected.

**Note:** For Eclipse 3.6 (Helios), you should use the updated JAR(s). See the comments by @Supressingfire and @Milo.

Note: on Eclipse 3.6(Helios), step 3 (artifacts.xml) is not necessary.
Tested on Ubuntu Eclipse 3.6:
Version: Helios Service Release 2
Build id: 20110218-0911

Comment: You could select your own answer as the official one if you want (no reputation gain in this gain, though)

Comment: I believe the new URL is ftp://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/eclipse/eclipse/updates/3.6/R-3.6-201006080911/plugins/org.junit.source_4.8.1.v4_8_1_v20100427-1100.jar and the version would presumably be 4.8.1.v4_8_1_v20100427-1100

Comment: I haven't downloaded Eclipse 3.6 yet, so I just referenced your comment for now. I might update it later if I have time.

Comment: Just want to confirm that this solution works on 3.6 service release 1. I don't know whether it was necessary, but I also added the the jar for 3.8.2 source code, as I use Junit 3 launcher. Used the following two jars:
ftp://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/eclipse/eclipse/updates/3.6/R-3.6.1-201009090800/plugins/org.junit.source_3.8.2.v3_8_2_v20100427-1100.jar
ftp://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/eclipse/eclipse/updates/3.6/R-3.6.1-201009090800/plugins/org.junit.source_4.8.1.v4_8_1_v20100427-1100.jar

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.jdt/msg18596.html), if you have downloaded the SDK version of Galileo, you have the sources of the main plugins.

For JUnit, this would be:

```
 <pathTo>\eclipse-SDK-3.5-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.junit4.source_4.5.0.v20090423.jar
```

You can try to add that as a source file in the Source tab of a JUnit launcher configuration and see if that solves your issue when you are debugging your JUnit test and are stepping through JUnit native methods.

(Note: I have the x64 version of eclipse Galileo, but I believe the file is the same for the x32 or for other platforms)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't have the Eclipse SDK. However, I have found a way to do it without downloading the whole SDK. Please check my solution.

Comment: Are we supposed to manually download sources jars (from sites like https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/releases) or is there a maven dependency for it.

Comment: @testerjoe2 I believe (9 years later) I was trying to say you should have those source *already* when downloading the SDK version of Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

My eclipse version is 4.6.0, the only solution that has worked so far for me is to download the source file which named org.junit.source_4.12.0.v201504281640.jar  from ftp://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/eclipse/eclipse/updates/4.6/R-4.6-201606061100/plugins/, then placed it into eclipse\plugins, afterwards restart eclipse then the source file has bound to the appropiate junit jar file automatically.

[image: final result]

Answer (score 1):

@Hosam Aly answer also works in Eclipse 4.3.1:

1. The jar to download is [here](ftp://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/eclipse/eclipse/updates/4.3/R-4.3.1-201309111000/plugins/org.junit.source_4.11.0.v201303080030.jar)
2. The text to append to `eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.equinox.source` is 
   `org.junit.source,4.11.0.v201303080030,plugins/org.junit.source_4.11.0.v201303080030.jar,-1,false`
3. I did not need to change `artifacts.xml`