# Having trouble attaching JUnit sources in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, configuration

I've been trying to attach JUnit sources in my Eclipse Indigo. From within the IDE it doesn't work - there's a non-modifiable no source attachment (why?) . I tried following the advice in "[How do I configure JUnit's Source in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084176/how-do-i-configure-junits-source-in-eclipse)", with JUnit version 4.8.2, but that didn't work. It's possible I didn't follow the instructions there just right, but I don't see any indication of where I could have made a mistake.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You should download JUnit source jar manually and it put them to the plugin folder (don't forget eclipse -clean).

Download JUnit jars from here ftp://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/eclipse/eclipse/updates/3.7/R-3.7.1-201109091335/plugins/ (*junit*, source files and jdt).

This is not last version, but you can easily change it.