# Eclipse plugin to run specific method

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, emma

I am making plugin in Eclipse that would run selected method with specific parameters (right click on method in package explorer and choose "Check" runs selected method with specific parameters and shows results).

What would be the best way to run selected method without having to compile whole project and use reflection (as project might not be complete and might not even compile yet)? I will also have to use EMMA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on JUnit plugin and create similar implementation. I believe that it provides almost what you need except the fact that it works with JUnit tests only.

Comment: Maybe you could point me where can I download source code? Git links I found in stackoverflow [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8065045/2758938) doesn't work for me.

Comment: I did not manage to get anything useful from plugins source so I chose to load method from compiled class file using reflection. So this question is still kind of open, but since you are only one that tried to help.